# Orchard filter projection query based on another module field

Tags: filter, orchardcms, projection

On Orchard 1.6 I have defined a custom content type named Offer, this Offer has a pack field. On the page displaying one offer I want to display a short list of the other offers with the same pack.

To do this I have tried to make a projection but how can I specifiy in the query filter that the pack field must be equals to the pack field of the offer currently displaid?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a content handler to store the currently displayed content item for later use in the request:

```
public class MyContentHandler : ContentHandler
{
    readonly IOrchardServices orchardServices;

    public MyContentHandler (
        IOrchardServices orchardServices)
    {
        this.orchardServices = orchardServices;            
    }

    protected override void BuildDisplayShape(BuildDisplayContext context)
    {
        if (context.DisplayType == "Detail" && ((IShape)context.Shape).Metadata.Type == "Content" &&
            orchardServices.WorkContext.GetState<ContentItem>("currentContentItem") == null)
        {
            orchardServices.WorkContext.SetState("currentContentItem", context.ContentItem);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can write a projection filter using the content item reference stored in the state.  (See Orchard.Tags.Projections.TagsFilter as an example of how to write a projection filter.)

Comment: This solution will only work *after* the content will actually get displayed (display shape gets created). You won't be able to get the current item this way earlier.

Comment: You can use this in a view like... var item = WorkContext.GetState<ContentItem>("CurrentContentItem");

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is currently possible. You would have to write your own code to do this I am afraid.